# GetElementById giving ReferenceError in Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, getelementbyid

I have no idea what's going on because I have never had problems with JS but here we go. I keep getting an Uncaught ReferenceError in Chrome with this code:

```
function showShareButtons() {
    var buttons = getElementById("sharebtns");
    document.buttons.style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Why aren't you simply using `document.getElementById("sharebtns").style.visibility = 'visible';`?

Comment: I'll be adding more in that function. Thanks @Sarfraz and @Anonymous!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't simply declare `getElementById` by itself for a variable.  You would need to use [`document.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById):

```
function showShareButtons() {
    var buttons = document.getElementById("sharebtns");
    buttons.style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

Even though you eventually use document in your code, it would not be the same since the variable is unable to be declared as anything definitive.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById("sharebtns");
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be like:
`function showShareButtons() {
   var buttons = document.getElementById("sharebtns");
   buttons.style.visibility = 'visible';
}`